# how to create a image gallery with shaped border

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

Now I am working on a project with a image gallery having a shaped image border [here is the mock up](http://repo.maomaomikt.com/imgs/store-show.png), I have no idea about how to implement it. SVG? Canvas? Any one can give me help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's starting code using an html canvas for you to learn from.**

The idea is:

- draw multiple images horizontally on the canvas.
- overlay your design on the canvas so only a portion of the images are revealed.
- use requestAnimationFrame to change the offset of the images.
- repeat, repeat, repeat.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9v7ZF/

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var offsetX=-256;
        var direction=5;
        var fps = 60;


        var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
        var imagesOK=0;
        var imgs=[];
        imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/store-show.png");
        imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/slide1.jpg");
        imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/slide2.jpg");
        loadAllImages();

        function loadAllImages(){
            for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
                var img = new Image();
                imgs.push(img);
                img.onload = function(){ 
                    imagesOK++; 
                    if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                        animate();
                    }
                };
                img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
                img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
                img.src = imageURLs[i];
            }      
        }


        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                // Update the current offset of pictures
                if(offsetX<-256 || offsetX>0){
                    direction*=-1;
                }
                offsetX+=direction;

                // draw the pictures
                ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],offsetX,0);
                ctx.drawImage(imgs[2],offsetX+imgs[1].width,0);
                ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0);


            }, 1000 / fps);
        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=256 height=157></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, that's what I want, thanks markE. One more thing, how about the  others browsers which does not support canvas tag?

Answer (score 0):

Create an image that will hold only the border and some outside white space and inner side must be transparent.

The div that will hold the gallery image should have this image as background image ( the new image you have created ).

Set a fixed height and width of this container div, that's it. Your work is done. Hope you get this done.